# PowerApps Date Function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have created my first power app and in one of the fields I request users to input the date in MM/DD/YYYY format and it gets saved to my excel sheet in teams so for example User inputs "12/30/2021" it's getting saved to excel correctly but when I try to show the same details in Form View to users the date is showing as "44561" when I try to use the Datevalue formula `Text(DateValue(Parent.Default),DateTimeFormat.ShortDate)` it shows the date as 1/1/4456.

Any help would be appreciated here

Answer (score 1):

Excel presents dates in "# of days since the start of a given epoch". Your value of "44560" is the number of days since 1/1/1900* (Excel's time start epoch).

**To convert from Excel date to a human readable date in PowerApps, use:**

```
DateAdd(
  DateValue("12/30/1899"),
  44560,
  Days
)
```

*For backwards compatibility reasons ([old bug?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5ca3734d-b293-4a81-8784-c3f4f0606b91/date-incorrectly-stored-as-18991230-in-sql-server)), this needs to be changed to 12/30/1899

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean here if I use the formula above it will only convert my current date I have mentioned how will I use this dynamically to display the dates from excel in form view?

Comment: Substitute "44560" above with `Parent.Default`. Then wrap the whole thing in `Text(<above_code>, DateTimeFormat.ShortDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you will just need:

```
Text(Parent.Default),"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

This should show your Date in the correct Format.

If this is not working, perhaps you can add some sample Data and picture ?

BR
Marcel

Comment: No, Not working still showing me the date as 44560

Comment: Oh okay, could you tell me:
1. what time Format you use for excel
2. is your Cell formated as Date, or whatever
3. do you have a datepicker in your form or just a text field ?


Then i´ll try to rebuild the problem. Perhaps i can find a solution then.

Comment: Firstly thanks for all your help here, Yes I have formatted the cell in excel to date format "Short Date",  I don't have a date picker I have kept a text field for input in powerapps form with a hint "MM/DD/YYYY" letting the user know how to input the date.

Answer (score 0):

I once built an app to save the date and was able to reproduce your error.

[Picture APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt2aD.png)

I created the first data set with 12/30/2021 and got the same error. I then created the second line with 30/12/2021 and got a suitable result.

I have a suspicion that this could be related to the date format in Excel and in Powerapps.

But if you absolutely need the format: 12/30/2021, then I would try a little more.

Comment: I absolutely need that format as US clients use MM/DD/YYYY format